# Adding an index to a LINQ query

Tags: c#, linq, indexing

I'm trying to figure out how to add an index to a LINQ query to speed up searching

```
var confirmation = (from p in _database.Participations where (p.accountID == bulletin.receiverID && p.eventID == @event.ID) select p).FirstOrDefault();
```

I'd like to add an index on the p.eventID field

Thanks!

Comment: This isn't a LINQ problem or a C# problem. The index needs to be in your database - talk to your DBA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to add the index to the column in the database.

Linq to XXX just generates SQL

Comment: Alright thanks, I guess I misunderstood [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/aa336758#SelectIndexed)